# Issue while rendering the literal text

Tags: asp.net

I have a string like below

```
<meta property="og:title" content="test" />
```

This is already in the literal control in it's text property. When I see the rendered page.
It shows like below.

```
&lt;meta property=&quot;og:title&quot; content=&quot;test&quot; /&gt;
```

**EDIT**

Here is the source providing the final text...

```
public static void RenderName(Literal ltlMetaHolder, string contentName, string content)
{
    var metaTagFromat = "<TagName property=\"{0}\" content=\"{1}\" />";
    ltlMetaHolder.Text = string.Format(metaTagFromat, contentName, content);

}
```

**Expected result**

```
<meta property="og:title" content="test" />
```

**Actual result**

```
&lt;meta property=&quot;og:title&quot; content=&quot;test&quot; /&gt;
```

Comment: I didn't understand! Do you have that string inside Text property of a Literal? From code? From markup? What do you see on the page? What do you except?

Comment: I have made updates in my query. Please check.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should set the [`LiteraControl`'s Mode property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.literal.mode.aspx) to `PassThrough`.
Then the contents of the control are not modified.

The default is `Transform`:

> Unsupported markup-language elements are removed from the contents of
>   the control. If the Literal control is rendered on a browser that
>   supports HTML or XHTML, the control's contents are not modified.

```
ltlMetaHolder.Mode = LiteralMode.PassThrough
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do so

```
public class MetaHelpers {
    public String WriteMeta(String property, String content) {
        return String.Format(@"<meta property=""{0}"" content=""{1}"" />", property, content);
    }
}
```

and in ASPX page

```
<head runat="server">
<title></title>
<%= MetaHelpers.WriteMeta("og:title", "test") %>
```